# Using .apply() on column with str and datetime format observations

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column df['Elapsed_time'] which is a mix of 'null' and time differences:

**df['Elapsed_time']**

---

'null'

---

0 days 00:05:08

---

0 days 01:10:50

---

'null'

I want to create a categorical variable based on this column for any time differences greater than 5 minutes. I set a condition function to filter based on observation, but am thinking I may need to separate the dataframe for observations containing "null", but this seems like a situation where .apply() should work. What am I doing wrong?

```
# Define the necessary data conditions in function
def condition(x):
    if x == "null":
        return "N/A"
    elif x < threshold:
        return "Momentary"
    else:
        return "Sustained"

# Applying the conditions
df['Duration_Type'] = df['Elapsed_time'].apply(condition)
```

Trying this, I get the error:

```
elif x < time_thres:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

Comment: provide sample data , but the error message is clear

Comment: Try to convert each cells in seconds.. currently you have a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out my problem. The observation was "N/A" and not "null". The logic was otherwise correct. Here is the working code:

```
def condition(x):
    if x == "N/A":
        return "N/A"
    elif x != "N/A":
        if x < time_thres:
            return "Momentary"
        else:
            return "Sustained"
```